# I have a Dataframe with very long text content and I wish to save it as a table (in .PNG) but text is getting cropped out

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I used the following code in order to save a dataframe as a picture

```
import dataframe_image as dfi
dfi.export(df,"df.png")
```

where `df` is the dataframe but ended up getting cropped text. It retains only the part of the text that can fit within a single line which does not help my use case.

I'm a newbie to python
Can someone please help? I would prefer to get the text wrapped so that I dont lose on any content

Comment: Could you also explain what is your use case for exporting data tables (programatically) as png? It may make sense to format the tables in a different program. To what extent does this need to be automated?

Comment: @SanjayManohar: The use case is that I need dataframes in tabular format for including in a PDF file. Can you please suggest any ideas?

Comment: Any probelm with CSV -> Excel -> screenshot?  If you want the PNG to look nice, you probably want to use a spreadsheet program. You may be able  automate this if needed using VBA.

Comment: The idea was to automate the entire process, till the point of PDF generation. Since there are a lot many tables and the activity is daily, I will try with VBA, thanks.

Comment: OK What are you using to generate the PDF? Usually it  is best if the table in the PDF would have text rather than image.  Can you output the table as  HTML instead, and include those in the PDF? Or even as SVG?

Comment: Thats an idea I have started working on, table in the HTML format. Thank you for your time and input Sanjay